# Create a greave (cuts) or combine two objects?

Tags: modeling, unity

I am trying to figure out what would be the best option to achieve the following result in Unity for my game background frame.

[image]

As you can see there are cuts in the frame. Tried with loop-cut and extrude. But then in Unity, those cuts are not make the black line affect.

Another option would be to create separate line objects and embed in main frame and then I could apply black color to line objects.

Or any better suggestion? Just need an advice what would be the right approach for this scenario.

Br, Maris

Comment: I'm a fan of the quick and easy solution. A single black quad set just behind the whole thing.  Forget about connecting everything together, just separate the buttons and let the backplate show through the cracks

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Will try it out.